# what is significance of __ref and is it efficient to use __ref to avoid modpost warnings?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am very new to linux-kernel. And i have following doubt.

suppose i have a function named : void foo1() and this function is calling other function foo2() which is: void __cpuinit foo2().

Now modpost will report the section mismatch warning. Now in this case we have these option:

1) we annotate the function foo1() with __cpuinit.

2) we remove __cpuinit from foo2()

3) we annotate __ref to function foo1()

Now in my case i can't go for option 1 and 2. So i have to go for option 3.
My questions;

- **how differently it will effect the memory ?** (how it will be different from case of option 1 and 2 in terms of memory consumption? is __ref remains in memory for long duaration ?)
- **it is Ok to use __ref?**

Answer (score 2):

`__ref` just suppresses the warning.
It does not remove the *reason* for the warning, i.e., when you call `foo2()` from `foo1()`, the kernel can still blow up.

You can use `__ref` only when you have ensured that `foo1()` does not *actually* call `foo2()` after the `__cpuinit` code has been freed.

Comment: But how these warnings are get surpassed. Is it like some local data structure is maintained ? Or some section memory is used to sort out this at run time ?

Comment: It puts the code into a different section that is not checked.